# fbDidLogin did not called at first time in iOS. So I modified, is this the right process?

Tags: ios, facebook, fbconnect, facebook-login

My fbDidLogin delegate method didn't called at first time. I searched and found ["fbDidLogin not called"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244609/fbdidlogin-not-called) and ["IOS - Facebook SDK fbDidLogin not called — initialize view controllers"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024446/ios-facebook-sdk-fbdidlogin-not-called-initialize-view-controllers) and handled the facebook url into my Application Delegate correctly. But fbDidLogin method didn't called. So I searched again. Someone says in ["Problems with fbDidLogin never called iOS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044412/problems-with-fbdidlogin-never-called-ios) to change

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];
```

into

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:YES];
```

in my ***Facebook.m*** file. After doing that my facebook login view just changed, yet couldn't get what I need. 
 In that situation what I did? I added a line

```
[facebook logout:self];
```

right after

```
[facebook authorize:permissions];
```

Because I thought there is a problem in login or/and logout syncronisation, so if I call facebook logout method it might (yes, MIGHT) work.
Voila! it does work, at least for me.
Now all I want to ask you, is there any problem or logical error in my process? And is there a better way to do so?