# Close the app in 'applicationDidEnterBackground'

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an iOS app and for several reasons I need to close it when the user clicks the home button of the device. I can't support background.

I now there is an option called `Application does not run in background`, but I can't use it because there is a bug from Facebook sdk that makes impossible to authenticate with Facebook when this option is in use. [Here is the bug report at Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/414563691940501?browse=search_506e2a4ecd68e7258709929).

So I don't know what to do, how can I restart it? An `[[NSThread mainThread] exit]` in `applicationDidEnterBackground`?

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The legal (Apple will approve the app) way is set or create the key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES` in the `Info.plist`.

To get this as action you would need `exit(0)` or `[[NSThread mainThread] exit]`, but this is against the Human Interface Guidelines from Apple

So what you could also do is just design all your views in a manner that they have a reset function . Then when `applicationDidEnterBackground` store that you need to reset on next startup or directly call reset on all active views in `applicationWillEnterBackground`

So your App didn't really restart, but all your views look like this. To give you an advice, I would design my app in a manner that it doesn't shutdown itself when i quit. This is no good user experience.. Once clicked the home button and all your data is away, same when you receive a call.

Comment: same as @danh...my app is not gonna get approved by Apple if I use exit() right? So that's not a good solution... I need the app in the market.

Comment: No to get approved the solution is to create the key UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend in the Info.plist and set it to true

Comment: Yes, but I cant use that option because there is a bug related with facebook-sdk, I can't authenticate with fb if that option is on. That's why I'm not using it...

Comment: You can just authenticate via the browser (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7048123/1578508) or use the SocialApi of iOS 6 to use UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend. Or if you really want to authenticate via the sdk you need to implement my alternative solution having a reset on every object that is active.

Comment: Another user also just changed the authentication method (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7049746/1578508) to [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:YES];

Comment: The socialapi of ios6 was just one possibility I mentioned. Just authenticate via safari or use another possibility i mentioned in my post and the comments

Comment: But I'm almost sure that option is not available in sdk 3.1... I'm going to google about it anyway! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Plain old `stdlib.h exit()` will terminate the app, though it violates [apple guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW1) (see "Don't Quit Programmatically").

Your app won't perform any background actions if you don't initiate any.

Comment: ok, But my app is not gonna get approved by Apple if I use exit() right? So that's not a good solution... I need the app in the market.

Comment: I had one approved using exit, before I discovered that it was a no-no.  But the good solution is to not initiate background action.  Why wouldn't the os natural exit process work fine?

Comment: Natural exit process? you mean the "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend"? I can't use that because Facebook-sdk has a bug with it...

Comment: I just mean doing nothing.  Don't initiate any background tasks, and let the app termination get taken care of for you.

Comment: Yes, but I have server connections, that take at least 10 seconds to end, if the user closes the app I can't correctly finish  those conections and when the app comes to foreground it will not behave correctly... so I need to restart the app...

Comment: This is just a bug in your application. Fix it instead of killing the app all the time!

Comment: NSURLConnection implements cancel.  Before you become inactive, cancel any running connection.  It will send no further delegate messages after getting canceled.